# Angular controller does not load when testing with Poltergeist/Capybara

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, poltergeist

I am working with rails/angular for the first time and I'm just now learning to test angular with poltergeist/capybara.  Everything angular is working fine in the actual browser but appears DOA when in testing.  I have tried using the gem 'capybara-angular' but none of the 3 or 4 configurations I tried did anything (let alone anything helpful).  I tried suppressing the JS errors which actually lets poltergeist get to the actual test but that fails, of course, because angular is not initialized.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I haven't even been able to find anybody else experiencing this error after 2 hours of searching.

The error:
    Failure/Error: click_link "Search"

```
 Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
   One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).

   Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'mainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

rails_helper.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :type => :feature) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

angular_test_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature "angular test" do
    let(:email){ "test@user.com" }
    let(:password){ "password123" }

before do
    User.create!(email: email,
                password: password,
                password_confirmation: password)
end

    scenario "Angular App is working" do
        visit "/"

        #login
        fill_in "Email", with: "test@user.com"
        fill_in "Password", with: "password123"
        click_button "Log in"

        #Check that navigation worked
        expect(page).to have_content("Home")

        #Test the nav
        click_link "Search"

        #Check that navigation worked
        expect(page).to have_content("Search")


        fill_in "keywords", with: "some item"
        within "section div h3" do
            expect(page).to have_content("some item")
        end
    end 
end
```

### EDIT:

Angular bindings are working on a test page like this:

```
<input name="test" ng-model="test">
<p>{{ test }}</p>
```

However, controllers do not load.

### EDIT 2:

I figured since things are working in dev but not test that something bad is happening in the asset pipeline and started googling.  I stumbled on this blog: http://www.gbonfant.com/blog/debugging-javascript-capybara/ (Better JavaScript errors in Capybara tests)

Better error descriptions sounded great, obviously, so I added `config.assets.debug = true` to `/config/environments/test.rb` and now the tests are passing without any errors.  I suspect per Tom Walpole's comment that this works because Rails is serving non-concatenated assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using PhantomJS 2.1+ -  PhantomJS < 2.0 did not have support for Function.prototype.bind() which is required by angular

Comment: I'm running PhantomJS 2.1.1

Comment: @CarlOverton Ok -- are there any other JS errors reported -- one difference between dev and test mode is that in test mode most JS files are concatenated which means an error in one can prevent processing the rest - this doesn't happen in dev mode since each file is served separately so an error in one doesn't prevent code in other files from running.

Comment: Looking back the same error occurs twice in a row per failure.

I figured since things are working in dev but not test that something bad is happening in the asset pipeline and started googling.  I stumbled on this blog: http://www.gbonfant.com/blog/debugging-javascript-capybara/

Better error descriptions sounded great, obviously, so I added`config.assets.debug = true` to `/config/environments/test.rb` and now the tests are passing without any errors.

Am I correct in assuming this un-compiling has fixed the issue as you described it?  Now I'm wondering where this other error is. . .

Comment: Correct - with debug turned on the files are not concatenated, so you either have an error or order issue in your JS files (note - you actually want concatenation in test mode because thats how production mode will be) Load up dev mode in a real browser and see if any errors are raised in the console there - it may point you towards which file the issue is in/with.

Comment: No errors in dev mode.  The app is quite small at the moment and both of the controllers are loading and working as expected.

Comment: @CarlOverton Is the repo public?  If so I can take a look -- otherwise it seems to be something with the concatenation/uglification or order of inclusion of your JS assets and you'll need to debug there to find it

Comment: @CarlOverton Ok -- for some reason your asset pipeline isn't actually recompiling the assets when your assets change -- force a recompile with `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and your tests pass -- I don't have time to diagnose the asset pipeline currently, but may later if you havent figured it out by then

Comment: Thanks for your time Tom, I'll take a look at that and see what I can figure out.